# Focus on google searchbar after a word

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

With <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> you get to the google **addressbar**. Then one can type something, after what is searched:

[image: Addressbar search]

After hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>, you get the results:

[image: Google results]

Now, I'd like to **add** something after the word that I was searching for in the **search bar**:

[image: Google search bar]

Is there a keyboard shortcut for it?

Answer (score 0):

If "Google Instant predictions" is enabled in Search Settings, you just need to start typing after completing the initial search and the text will be typed in the search bar, after your initial search.

You can check your search settings here:  https://www.google.com/preferences

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just start typing the additional words.

Google will detect the keystrokes and will automatically append the characters to the existing search keys.

This will work on any search tab (All, Videos, News) except for Images. It's either a bug, or it was intentionally disabled by Google for image search.